# How can i export single content node (or) selected content nodes using drush command

Tags: 7, drush

I am using drupal 7. i created three basic pages name it as node1, node2, node3 when i export node using node-export-export command all pages(node1,node2,node3) as in one xml file. my intention is to export and import each node (or) selected nodes at a time. Please help me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush command node-export-export accepts arguments ... You can see documentation of any drush command using below syntax..

```
drush help command-name
```

In your case

```
drush help node-export-export
```

Arguments:
 nids                                      A list of space-separated node IDs 
                                           to export.

For Example

```
drush node-export-export 45 46 47
```

export nodes with node IDs 45, 46, 47

Comment: awesome @anil Sagar . tq so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716 for a full explanation"

Comment: How Can i add --destination for this one ?